# jquery iframe html() - I can access to iframe, but can't get its content

Tags: jquery, iframe

this has been discussed several times, but i just can't make it work.

i've one iframe created on the fly, i can acess its properties, like width or css styles, but can't access to its innerHTML.

this is my code, what i'm missing here?

thanks!

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.frameBorder = 0;
iframe.width = '100%';
iframe.height = '180px';
iframe.src  = 'javascript:void(0);';
iframe.id = '_input_'+que_evento_id;
$(iframe).css('margin-top', '5px');
$(iframe).css('background-color', '#ffffff');
$(iframe).css('border', 'solid 1px #ff7223');
var conteudo = $('#span_'+que_evento_id+'').text();
var doc = '<html><head><meta http-equiv=\'Content-Type\' content=\'text/html; charset=UTF-8\'><title>Editar</title></head><body style=\'padding:5px\'>'+conteudo+'</body></html>';
iframe_doc = iframe.contentWindow.document;
try {
    iframe_doc.designMode = 'on';
} catch ( e ) {
    $(iframe_doc).focus(function() { iframe_doc.designMode(); } );
}
iframe_doc.open();
iframe_doc.write(doc);
iframe_doc.close();

width = $('#_input_'+que_evento_id+'').attr('width');
console.log(width); // returns 100% wich is correct
o_que_vamos_editar = $('#_input_'+que_evento_id+'').contents().find('body').html();
console.log('log '+o_que_vamos_editar); // returns "log "
```

Comment: is the iframe in the same domain as your page?

Comment: yes, it is created runtime with var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');

Comment: edited the question code with the complete iframe creation process.